# Best way to represent reference data in Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, data-modeling

Lets say I have a Product that can have any amount of attributes... and those attributes are limited to specific options.  A product can have (valid options below each):

- Color

  - Red
  - Blue
  - Green
- Category

  - Sports
  - Formal
  - Kids
- Waterproof

  - Yes
  - No

The list could go on.  Is there anyway to represent this in active record with a single table?  I think it would be ideal to have a single reference data table that looks something like:

```
create_table :attritubes do |t|
  t.string :name # Red, Blue, Green, Sports, Formal...
  t.string :field_type # Color, Category, Waterproof...
end
```

It would seem like a waste to have a model for every attribute since it doesn't really do much.  Is this a case where I have a generic model called Attribute that a product has many of?  Or is there a way for active record to differentiate the attributes by a column (making up this syntax):

```
belongs_to :color, class_name: :attribute, where(field_type: 'color')
```

After typing that out, it almost looks like a scope... is that a better way to go?

Comment: How about using a polymorphic association? I can't quite put the finger on the exact model relationships, but the '_type' field there seems like a strong indicator of a use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single table for attributes like

```
create_table :attritubes do |t|
  t.string :color 
  t.string :category 
  t.boolean :waterproof
end
```

& then take the data in enums like

```
enum color: { red:0, blue:1, green:2 }
enum category: { sports:0, formals:1, kids:2 }
enum waterproof: { no:0, yes:1 }
```